# Is request header "referer" always sent when from one page to other when both the pages are in HTTPS protocol

Tags: java, https

Request header called as `"referer"` `request.getHeader("referer")` is always sent from one page to other when both the pages belong to HTTPS Protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least under normal browsing, Yes.  The http-referrer header is sent by the browser regardless of SSL.  I'm not sure what happens when browsing in your browser's "privacy" mode though.  It likely varies depending on the browser/version.